# Minimalistic complete 3D editor --?

Tags: 3d

Anyone know such software or workflow ?

It should be simple and logical . Not alike requiring to make a new tool just to measure distance between points on geometries as Houdini, or having a literally insane interface as Blender or Zbrush . It should be a tool, to make the work, not to puzzle the controls all over the time . And so it wouldn't require a damn research just to find a button, for every simple task .

Story

> ~4 years ago i needed to make and animate a 3D model, after struggling trough search, i used Sculptris and then did all the rest with Houdini . But it still was pretty long, bothering, and i already forgot almost everything . Now i need the complete editing suite, to support UE4 project .

#### It should have at least

- Per-primitive editing .
- Weighed and sectional skinning .
- Kinematic-, per-bone- and editing- interpolation-animating .
- Managing and applying multiple animation sequences in the same time to the same bones -- with merging .

#### And preferably

- Sculpting with auto polygon division .
- On-model texture painting with layers, custom-image-stamp-drawing and uniform pattern painting (strokes aligning) .

Relatively long set-up is fine .

Comment: FYI: Blender's interface was redesigned in 2.8. Of course, Blender still has all the features...

Comment: @ThomasWeller this is crazy X) , looks promising, thanks .

Comment: @ThomasWeller so far looks good, the only Blender's issue was the interface, so i got surprised that something such good could happen :) . you can post it as an answer .